# Days are getting plus one when printing using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, date-format

I am facing a weird problem with AngularJS date format -

Following is the date I am getting in response -

```
"start_date":"2014-08-16T18:30:00.000Z"
```

Now when I am applying AngularJS date formats filter like -

```
response.data.start_date = $filter('date')(response.data.start_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

My date is added +1 and its showing like this in the form -

```
08/17/2014
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

**FYI** - I am on my local server(localhost) so nothing coming from another server.

Comment: What time zone are you in? The `Z` on that string means it's in "Zulu" time (GMT/UTC). There are timezones where 18:30 on the 16th GMT **is** on the 17th local time (Beijing, Seoul, Tokyo, ...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IST is my timezone

Comment: Just for completeness, I should mention that if AngularJS or you are parsing that date using JavaScript's built-in parsing, you'd have the same situation even if the `Z` weren't there. In ISO-8601, the string *without* the Z should be "local time" (so, IST in your case), but JavaScript's *very similar* format [is not ISO-8601](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2014/07/javascripts-datetime-format-is-not-iso.html), and one of the key differences is that if there's no timezone indicator on the string, `Z` is assumed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thx for the info Sir...and I subscribed to your blog..as it looks informative to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Z` on that string means it's in "Zulu" time (GMT/UTC). There are timezones where 18:30 on the 16th GMT **is** on the 17th local time. One of those places is India, which is GMT+0530 (you've said you're in the IST time zone). So 18:30 + 5.5 hours = midnight the next day, local time in India.

Comment: Ok..got it thx for the info..will accept it in 7 min(stack time limit)